# how to extract a number from a string if I know when its starting and when its finishing

Tags: regex, scala, regex-negation

for example:

I have the following string

```
"somestringthatcanbeanything theStringBeforeTheNumber20.47theStringAfterTheNumber somestringthatcanbeanything"
```

so the number is always between

```
theStringBeforeTheNumber{number}theStringAfterTheNumber
```

What I want is to extract the number from the whole string, how can I do that? im using scala how should my regex look like?   `val myRgx: Regex = """myRegexGoesHere""".r`

Comment: What language or tool are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen im using scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your suggested pattern, slightly modified as:

```
val string = "theStringBeforeTheNumber20.47theStringAfterTheNumber"
val pattern = """theStringBeforeTheNumber(.*?)theStringAfterTheNumber""".r
pattern.findAllIn(string).matchData foreach {
    m => println(m.group(1))
}
```

The quantity in parentheses `(.*?)` is a capture group and it uses a lazy dot.  This says to match everything between the first string and the first occurrence of the second string.  We print out the first capture group in the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the starting and finish string, I think that is better do a substring() because in general the regexp is costly.
For example 
substring(indexOf(theStringBeforeTheNumber) + length(theStringBeforeTheNumber) , indexOf(theStringAfterTheNumber))
Also you must consider if the initial and final string are equals because the indexes, in that case you have do some extra calculation.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using Regex along with verifying the extracted number:

```
import scala.util.Try

val s = "somestringthatcanbeanything theStringBeforeTheNumber20.47theStringAfterTheNumber somestringthatcanbeanything"

val pattern = """.*?theStringBeforeTheNumber([0-9.-]*)theStringAfterTheNumber.*""".r

val number: Double = s match {
  case pattern(num) => Try(num.toDouble).getOrElse(-999)
  case _ => -999
}
number: Double = 20.47
```